# Web Part Leaves Behind Code When Deleted

Tags: web-part, aspx

When I delete a custom Web Part from a Sharepoint page, even though the WYSIWYG editor shows nothing even when I backspace, if I look at the HTML, there's code left there by the web part, that usually follows a pattern similar to this (with different ids, of course):

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox">
    <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 8a946d26-c214-49f8-933c-8790feb53ed5" id="div_8a946d26-c214-49f8-933c-8790feb53ed5" unselectable="on">
    </div>
    <div id="vid_8a946d26-c214-49f8-933c-8790feb53ed5" unselectable="on" style="display:none">
    </div>
</div>
```

This can mess with some code I have, plus generally just is ugly and bad for the DOM. Plus, my users won't check for this, so I can have pages with a lot of bloat because of this invisible code from them deleting web parts.

Is there any way to disable this from happening, or am I doing something wrong?

Also let me know if you need more context for this question.

Comment: what is the sharepoint version